# java null pointer exception

Tags: java, android

Based on different SO questions I understand what the java.null.pointer exception is I am just not sure why it occurs in this case. In summary a reference to a variable declared as a reference type not yet defined.

I have 2 java files RegisterActivity.java and AppController.java.

The following call in the RegisterActivity.java file results in a java.null.pointer exception:

> AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

This is the method in the AppController file:

> public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
>           return mInstance;
>       }

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }


//RegisterActivity.java
 public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
 ...
     private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                          final String password) {
          ...
          AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
     }

 ...
 }
```

> 07-01 16:33:17.757 995-995/mobi.blessd.user.blessd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: mobi.blessd.user.blessd, PID: 995
>                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                            at mobi.blessd.user.blessd.activity.RegisterActivity.registerUser(RegisterActivity.java:189)
>                                                                            at mobi.blessd.user.blessd.activity.RegisterActivity.access$300(RegisterActivity.java:35)
>                                                                            at mobi.blessd.user.blessd.activity.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:84)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
>                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

My source code is from the following tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: Please post both classes so that we can see the detailed information about what you are asking, also check out this link for more info on `NullPointerException` :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: is the solution to first create an instance of a AppController object, prior to the getInstance call in the RegistrActivity file.

Comment: Is AppController your Application class? I.e. do you have `<application android:name=".AppController" ... >` in the manifest?

Comment: please check you manifest file, as suggested by @Sergey

Comment: Did you "Add the AppController class to <application> tag"?

Comment: THANKS everyone that was the problem no application name tag in the manifest file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the `AppControler` to your manifest?

```
<application
        android:name=".AppController" //this one
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: But AppController is the Application. It should be created before any activity by Android. The only variant I see: it is not true application class, it isn't declared in manifest.

Comment: yeah, i agree. It should be created before any activity

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, tho the code looks allot like a Singleton Design Pattern

Comment: THANKS everyone that was the problem no application tag in the manifest file