# android: custom AppController NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-manifest

I am developing an application which i wanna use a login and a register form. For that reason i am following this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/).

This tutorial ask me to create a new java file with name `AppController` that extends Application. I did this and all the stuff, but when i run my app i get a *NullPointerException*, probably because i have not declared the `AppController` in the Manifest.

I have seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147355/java-null-pointer-exception) where the poster had the same issue with me. Everyone told him to add the `AppController` to the Manifest, under the `application` tag. I tried also to do this but my app crashes.
I have a lot of Activities tha are declared in the Manifest with the `<activity>` tag under the `<application` tag. A piece of my Manifest is below for example.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/getaroom"
    android:label="@string/welcome"
    android:name="com.example.package.AppController"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">"


    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CreateAccountActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_create_account"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

As you can see i have declared the `AppController` in the application tag, but then app crashes.
This is a java file that extends `Application`, my other java files extends `ActionBarActivity`.

My question is, how can i declare the new file in the Manifest? Or how can i add a new file that extends Activity to an already existed app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the line of code which causes the error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the line is android:name="com.example.package.AppController"

Comment: Did you use the right package name?

Comment: Only Java code can cause an exception. Look at the logcat to find which line it is.

Comment: @Fuyuba yes! This is not the one i use in my app though. This is the proper way to declare classes that extends Application?

Comment: please post the error stack trace

Comment: Please post AppController class and stacktrace

Comment: If you follow the link for the other SO thread i am posting you can see exactly what i mean. I can post tha stacktrace but my questions will be the same

Comment: In order to help you answer your question, you need to answer ours. You have left out critical information which is necessary to figure out what is wrong in your app.

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept that answer. It may help others who have similar problems and it will get the question off the "unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure it out, i just have to declare the AppController in the Manifest but somehow i get an error everytime i declare it. I use `android:name=".Packagename.AppController"` and now it is working. thanks for the help!